# How can i plot a graph that fills the area under a curve using the mean of multiple datapoints?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

I am having trouble plotting a graph that fills the area under a curve consisting of the mean of my datapoints. When I try to attempt this, it looks like the image below.
I would ideally like a the green line to be a smoothed curve consisting of the mean of the "normalized_gfp" datapoints for each timepoint with green fill between that and 0.0.
I hope this makes sense.

```
coeff<-1/80000
p1<-ggplot(lf_test, aes(x=time)) +
  #geom_smooth(aes(y=normalized_gfp),size=2, span=0.3,fill = "#90d850", color = "#00BA38")+
  geom_area(aes(y=normalized_gfp),fill = "#90d850", color = "#266825", alpha = 0.4, size = 0.5)+
  geom_smooth( aes(y=od / coeff), size=2, span=0.26,color="tomato",fill="tomato") +   
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,80000),
                     name = "Relative Flourescence [RFU]/[OD] ",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 10^(.x*coeff)-1, breaks = c(0.01,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2.0,2.5,5.0,7.5,10.0,15.0,20.0), name = 'OD600'))+
  theme_grey() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#90d850", size=13),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "tomato", size=13)
  ) 
print(p1)
```

[image]

The data consists of triplicate experiments and there are thus 3 datapoints for each timepoint. The data is below:

```
     time          media id   od   gfp normalized_gfp
180 21.36 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.21  1839       8757.143
181 21.36 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.25  4363      17452.000
182 21.36 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.53  2204       4158.491
183 21.60 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.22  1966       8936.364
184 21.60 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.28  4517      16132.143
185 21.60 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.54  2302       4262.963
186 22.08 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.24  2084       8683.333
187 22.08 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.31  4659      15029.032
188 22.08 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.56  2395       4276.786
189 22.32 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.25  2209       8836.000
190 22.32 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.34  4953      14567.647
191 22.32 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.57  2484       4357.895
192 22.56 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.27  2323       8603.704
193 22.56 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.38  5305      13960.526
194 22.56 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.59  2687       4554.237
195 23.04 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.27  2450       9074.074
196 23.04 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.41  5588      13629.268
197 23.04 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.60  2886       4810.000
198 23.28 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.28  2664       9514.286
199 23.28 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.44  5713      12984.091
200 23.28 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.61  2993       4906.557
201 24.00 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.31  2934       9464.516
202 24.00 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.50  6357      12714.000
203 24.00 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.64  3253       5082.812
204 24.24 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.32  3077       9615.625
205 24.24 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.53  6572      12400.000
206 24.24 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.66  3583       5428.788
207 24.72 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.33  3084       9345.455
208 24.72 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.57  6653      11671.930
209 24.72 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.68  3643       5357.353
210 24.96 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.35  3355       9585.714
211 24.96 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.59  6785      11500.000
212 24.96 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.69  3816       5530.435
213 25.20 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.35  3367       9620.000
214 25.20 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.59  7022      11901.695
215 25.20 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.71  4000       5633.803
216 25.68 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.37  3415       9229.730
217 25.68 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.61  7327      12011.475
218 25.68 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.73  4206       5761.644
219 25.92 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.37  3665       9905.405
220 25.92 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.63  7718      12250.794
221 25.92 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.74  4332       5854.054
222 26.40 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.38  3746       9857.895
223 26.40 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.64  8072      12612.500
224 26.40 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.76  4475       5888.158
225 26.64 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.38  3787       9965.789
226 26.64 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.66  8444      12793.939
227 26.64 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.77  4882       6340.260
228 26.88 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.38  4201      11055.263
229 26.88 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.67  8715      13007.463
230 26.88 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.78  4984       6389.744
231 27.36 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.39  6190      15871.795
232 27.36 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.69  8929      12940.580
233 27.36 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.80  5275       6593.750
234 27.60 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.38  8318      21889.474
235 27.60 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.68  9266      13626.471
236 27.60 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.81  5354       6609.877
237 28.08 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.37  9035      24418.919
238 28.08 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.67  9501      14180.597
239 28.08 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.82  5740       7000.000
240 28.32 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.37  9063      24494.595
241 28.32 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.65  9872      15187.692
242 28.32 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.83  5887       7092.771
243 28.56 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.37  9192      24843.243
244 28.56 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.64  9867      15417.188
245 28.56 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.84  6165       7339.286
246 29.04 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.36  8884      24677.778
247 29.04 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.61  9517      15601.639
248 29.04 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.85  6402       7531.765
249 29.28 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.36  8959      24886.111
250 29.28 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.60  9629      16048.333
251 29.28 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.86  6514       7574.419
252 30.00 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.34  8863      26067.647
253 30.00 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.56  9348      16692.857
254 30.00 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.87  6953       7991.954
255 30.24 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.34  8725      25661.765
256 30.24 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.55  9123      16587.273
257 30.24 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.88  7018       7975.000
258 30.72 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.35  8813      25180.000
259 30.72 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.54  8930      16537.037
260 30.72 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.88  7123       8094.318
261 30.96 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.33  8710      26393.939
262 30.96 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.54  9012      16688.889
263 30.96 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.89  7506       8433.708
264 31.20 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.34  8596      25282.353
265 31.20 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.53  8761      16530.189
266 31.20 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.88  8225       9346.591
267 31.68 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.34  8168      24023.529
268 31.68 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.53  8609      16243.396
269 31.68 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.89  9175      10308.989
270 31.92 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.32  8189      25590.625
271 31.92 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.51  8574      16811.765
272 31.92 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.88  9713      11037.500
273 32.40 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.32  7973      24915.625
274 32.40 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.52  8219      15805.769
275 32.40 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.89 10677      11996.629
276 32.64 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.32  8079      25246.875
277 32.64 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.50  8280      16560.000
278 32.64 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  3 0.89 10833      12171.910
279 32.88 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  1 0.33  7797      23627.273
280 32.88 IO+CasA+Fe_gfp  2 0.49  8071      16471.429
```

I hope everything makes sense, or i will be happy to ellaborate.
Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

As long as I understood, this should do the trick:

```
library(tidyverse)

coeff<-1/80000 

lf_test <- lf_test %>% group_by(time) %>% mutate(gfp_mn = mean(normalized_gfp))

# Use loess for a smooth line. 
lo1 <- loess(lf_test$gfp_mn~lf_test$time)

# Take the fitted values attribute. These will be new y values.
lf_test$smooth_y <- lo1$fitted

# Keep your original dataframe for the top half of the plot.
# Create a new dataframe to use for the smoothed area on bottom half.
df2 <- lf_test %>% group_by(time) %>% slice(n=1)

ggplot(lf_test, aes(x=time)) +
  geom_smooth( aes(y=od / coeff), 
              size=2,span=0.26,color="tomato",fill="tomato") +   
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,80000),
              name = "Relative Flourescence [RFU]/[OD] ",
              sec.axis = sec_axis(~ 10^(.x*coeff)-1, breaks =  
              c(0.01,0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2.0,2.5,
              5.0,7.5,10.0,15.0,20.0), name = 'OD600')) +
  geom_area(data=df2, aes(x=time, y=smooth_y),fill = "#90d850", 
              color = "#266825", alpha = 0.4, size = 0.5) +
  theme_grey() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#90d850", size=13),
              axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "tomato",
              size=13)
)
```

That gives me a figure like this:

[image]

> It seems like you what you were looking for was the `group_by()` and `mutate(mean())` statements to get your values. I had a problem with using `geom_area()` in the plot, so I changed that to `geom_ribbon()`. [Documentation says](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_ribbon.html) that `geom_area()` is a special example of `geom_ribbon()`.

I left the old description in case it's useful for you for other purposes.

In the original dataframe, `lf_test`, there are multiple rows with the same timestamp. That's what was creating the very jagged saw pattern in your `geom_area()`. I created `df2` so that it just has one row per timestamp. That works better with `geom_area()`.

If you want all of the rows, I would add small increments to each duplicated timestamp. For example, if there are three of 21.0, I would make them 21.1, 21.2., 21.3. Since you have that `id` column, you could create a new `time` column by doing something like `time+(id/100)` maybe. Then at least you'd have distinct times.

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot, is there possibly any way to smoothen the geom_ribbon line?